# Weirdness with pexpect when calling pg_dump

Tags: python, pexpect, pg-dump

Sorry if this is not allowed, I am still a newbie so please forgive me in advance. I'm curious on the behavior I'm noticing and wanted to get some input.

When calling `pg_dump`, it seems you now need to pass in a user promoted password, so my options here were limited and the use option was using `pexpect` to pass in the phrase.

Though, after sending the line, nothing happened and when logging to a file, all I could see was the password being sent but no output. I double/triple checked my command and it works (with the cli), so the below snippet should have worked just fine.

I tried `child.logfile_read` to determine the expected output and my `child.expect` was also correct.

```
password='test'
cmd = 'pg_dump --host {host} --port {port} --dbname {db} --username {username}\
    --file {filename} --table {table} --schema={schema}'.format(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        db=db,
        username=username,
        filename=filename,
        table=table,
        schema=schema
    )


child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(password)
child.read()
```

I just so *happened* to add a `child.read()` and boom, my file got exported as intended. This feels wrong to me and I tried a few different approaches and read through the documentation, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the fact that this actually works. I mean, per the [documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.read)

> This reads at most “size” bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes). If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF is reached. The bytes are returned as a string object. An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately

Why does this actually work? What am I missing? I feel like these are one of those cases where its going to bomb on me later because I don't actually understand what's happening under the hood.

My best guess is there is something weird happening with EOF and the command isn't actually processing but as soon as I use `child.read()`, it's actually completing the command? Not sure, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is EOF.

As implied by the excerpt from the pexpect docs you posted, `read` reads either the specified amount of bytes or until it encounters EOF. In your context, that means it *waits* for the child process to send EOF, which is equivalent to the process terminating.

Without the call to `read`, your Python process does not block until the child process completes. It ends right after the `child.sendline(password)` call returns.

Judging by the fact that you use `spawn`, I assume you are running this on a POSIX platform. That means, the pexpect child [is an instance of `ptyprocess.PtyProcess`](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/pty_spawn.py#L314).
The [`PtyProcess`](https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess/blob/master/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py#L128) class implements the `__del__` finalizer intending to ...

> [...] make[s] sure that no system resources are left open.

The finalizer [calls](https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess/blob/master/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py#L382) the [`close`](https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess/blob/master/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py#L393) method on the instance. That closes the file descriptor and calls [`terminate`](https://github.com/pexpect/ptyprocess/blob/master/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py#L622) to end the child process, either via SIGINT, SIGHUP or, if called with `force=True` (the default), SIGKILL ultimately.

So, when your Python process ends, right after `child.sendline(password)` returns, the interpreter starts cleaning up its memory space and executes the finalizer in the process. That terminates the execution of your `pg_dump` command before it even started writing to the output file.

You'll have to block your main process until your child process completes. `read` certainly does that, but you don't seem particularly interested in reading from the child. You could go for [`wait()`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.wait) instead:

> This waits until the child exits. This is a blocking call. This will not read any data from the child [...]

Comment: This makes so much more sense, thanks for the lengthy explanation, perfect example of an answer.CC: @shmee